# Random alphabet character encryption for each character of a string

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to write a write a code that encrypts a three letter word such as if the word "dog" was encrypted an example output could be mii, laz, fqy, zlp. I'm currently focusing on the encryption method at the moment. I've having a little trouble though replacing the letter thought. it's at line 22 where I make encryptString = to the replacement of ch. I eventually have to make this idea in a frame and panel, but I will tackle that later, for now I need to finish the concrete methods and ideas.

```
//*******************************************************
// Question2.java       Section: CSIT112_01SP16
//
// Author Usman Dawud Bashiru.
// Encrpyts and Decrpyts a three letter english word.
//
//*******************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Question2 implements Encode{

   String userInput, encryptString;
   int number, length;
   char letter, ch, firstch, secondch, thirdch;

   public String encrypt(String userInput){
      String result = "";
      this.userInput = userInput;
      for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++){
         ch = userInput.charAt(i);
         encryptString = userInput.replace(ch, (char)((int)(Math.random()*26) +96));
         result += encryptString;
      }
      System.out.println(result);
      return null;
   }

   public String decrypt(String encrpytString){
      this.encryptString = encrpytString;
      return null;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){

      Question2 passcode = new Question2();
      passcode.encrypt("dog");
   }
```

Here's my output, I know I'm a little close, but I'm hitting a wall right now.

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java Question2
jogdwgdos

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I'm slightly confused. What output are you expecting exactly?

Comment: I was expecting "jws" for the output, but ended up with jogdwgdos

Comment: RTFM for `Java: operator +=` may help... (I'm very interested how do you expect to decrypt the resulting string if you using random values to "encrypt" it :)  )

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Sure i'll keep you posted, but my idea to decrypt the message, is to list all the alphabet characters for the first letter and see if it matches and do it for the second and third.

Comment: This isn't encryption. This is scrambling.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `encrypt` method with this.

```
   public String encrypt(String userInput){
      String result = userInput;
      for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++){
         ch = userInput.charAt(i);
         result = result.replace(ch, (char)((int)(Math.random()*26) +96));
      }
      System.out.println(result);
      return result;
   }
```

**However**, your encryption scheme isn't going to work the way it is as you are using random to encrypt. Also, the `replace` method will replace ALL occurrences of that character. So if you were encrypting the String test, the line `result.replace` will replace ALL t characters.

Comment: I see what you're saying, this may not work because I will have to use the string of the encrypt method in the decrypt method as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I'm not sure if this is the best solution to it, but it works as planned for the encrpyt method.

```
public String encrypt(String userInput){
      String result = "";
      this.userInput = userInput;
      for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++){
         ch = userInput.charAt(i);
         encryptString = userInput.replace(ch, (char)((int)(Math.random()*26) +97));
         result += encryptString.charAt(i);
      }
      System.out.println(result);
      return null;
   }
```

Here's my output:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java Question2
xng

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```